# Why formatted date is giving previous century

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I have date in 4 digits. I came across inputs those are after 2050. In my application  `"0150"` means `January 01 2050`. But when i format it returns following output.

```
Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 PKT 1950




 public static Date getFormatDate( String newformat, String dateValue ) throws Exception {

        try {

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( newformat );
            java.util.Date newdate = simpleDateFormat.parse( dateValue );
            return newdate;
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            System.out.println( "Exception in converting date format --->" + e );
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {        
        System.out.println(getFormatDate( "MMyy", "0150" ));
    }
```

Any help in resolving this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's only 2013 and people are already trying to trim off the century again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `SimpleDateFormat` parses two digit year fields, so that the result is "within 80 years before and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created".

If you want to modify the behaviour to better match your requirement, you can use the method `set2DigitYearStart` to set the beginning of the 100-year period, into which your dates are mapped.

Answer (score 5):

From the SimpleDateFormat javadoc :

> For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or "yy"),
>   SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some
>   century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before
>   and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created.

In your case, 1950 is within 80 years before today.

In order to get the correct date (2050), you have to call [SimpleDateFormat.set2DigitYearStart(Date)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#set2DigitYearStart-java.util.Date-).